# CSS Padding and width

Tags: css

Consider the next code:

```
#container {
    width:500px;
}

#inside {
   padding:10px;
   width:100%;
}
```

If I choose width:100%; will it be the same as stating "width 480:px" (that is, calculating the padding already) or will it be as "width:500px"

Thanks

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like `width:500px` and adding the padding it will <strike>*push* the insides of</strike> *overflow* the `#container`..

But if `#inside` is a block element, then just giving the padding will make it behave as if it were `width:480px`

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/uA9LV/

Comment: Not exactly.  It won't push the insides of the #container at all.  Instead, #inside will end up outside of the container.

Comment: @Chris, indeed ... it was a figure of speech, but not appropriate in this case.. edited :)

Comment: BTW, I'm digging jsfiddle.net.  Looks like a really nice way to present code.

Comment: So what is the rule? I thought leaving the width property blank results in "width:100%".

Comment: @Joel, leaving it blank results to **total** width being 100%. Inclusive of borders and paddings.. so that is the way to go ..

Comment: I'm upvoting you for no other reason than the jsfiddle sample...well, that and you were the first one with a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same width as the parent container provided it's a block level element. So #inside will be 500px wide with 10px of padding on every side.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in a sample document and the container div only resized 3 sides (left, top, and bottom)..  and the inside div pushed it's boundaries outside of the container by 20px to the right.

I tested in IE8, Firefox 3.6.10, and the latest Chrome.  Using various doctypes had no effect.

The code I used was:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            width:500px;
            border: solid 1px blue;
        }

        #inside {
           padding:10px;
           width:100%;
           border: solid 1px red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inside">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** if you remove the Width declaration from the #inside div then you'll get exactly what you want.  Which is an inner div that is 480px in width + 10px on each side for padding.  See this link for more information on it: [Solving the CSS Padding problem](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/solving-the-css-padding-problem/).